# Getting returned "[object Object] NaN" - Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, nan, parseint

As the title says, when i execute my code, in the console i get returned `"[object Object] NaN"` (with quote marks in console)

As i am always not so sure what code to send out as their might be other factors involved, I am going to post all my code in

Main.Js

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var zombie1 = new Rectangle(300, 300, 20, 50);
var border = new Rectangle(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
var debugPlayer = new Rectangle(400, 400, 50, 50);

zombie1.ChangeColour("rgb(0, 0, 255)");
border.ChangeColour("rgb(150, 150, 150)");
border.ChangeThickness(300);
debugPlayer.ChangeColour("rgb(100, 100, 100)")


var playerup = "false"
var playerdown = "false"
var playerleft = "false"
var playerright = "false"

var update = function(){

    if (playerup == "true"){
        debugPlayer.y = debugPlayer.y - 1
    };
    if (playerdown == "true"){
        debugPlayer.y = debugPlayer.y + 1
    };
    if (playerleft == "true"){
        debugPlayer.x = debugPlayer.x - 1
    };
    if (playerright == "true"){
        debugPlayer.x = debugPlayer.x + 1
    };

    DoCollision(debugPlayer, zombie1);

    var processedZombiewidth = parseInt(zombie1.width, 10);
    console.log(debugPlayer.x, zombie1.x, debugPlayer + processedZombiewidth); // I am getting "400, 300, "[object Object] NaN" in console.

};
var makeScreen = function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

    border.Draw(ctx, "true");
    debugPlayer.Draw(ctx, "false")
    zombie1.Draw(ctx, "false");
};

var DoCollision = function(rect1, rect2){
    if (rect1.x > rect2.x){
        if (rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width){
            console.log("fat")
        };      
    };
};

var updateFunc = function(){
    update();
    makeScreen();
};



setInterval(function(){updateFunc();}, 1);




$(document).keyup(function(objEvent){
        objEvent ? keycode = objEvent.keyCode : keycode = event.keyCode; 
        console.log(keycode);

        if (keycode == 87){ //W
            playerup = "false"
        };
        if (keycode == 65){ //A
            playerleft = "false"
        };
        if (keycode == 83){ //S
            playerdown = "false"
        };
        if (keycode == 68){ //D
            playerright = "false"
        };

});
$(document).keydown(function(objEvent){
        objEvent ? keycode = objEvent.keyCode : keycode = event.keyCode;
        console.log(keycode);
        if (keycode == 87){ //W
            playerup = "true"
        };
        if (keycode == 65){ //A
            playerleft = "true"
        };
        if (keycode == 83){ //S
            playerdown = "true"
        };
        if (keycode == 68){ //D
            playerright = "true"
        };
});
```

rectangle.js

```
Rectangle = function(x, y, w, h){

this.colour = "rgb(0, 0, 0)"
this.thickness = 1

this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.w = w;
this.h = h; 

this.Draw = function(ctx, hollow){
    ctx.fillStyle = this.colour;
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.colour;

    if (hollow == "true"){
        ctx.lineWidth = this.thickness
        ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    };
    if (hollow == "false"){
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h)
    };

};
this.ChangeColour = function(colour){
    this.colour = colour
};
this.ChangeThickness = function(thickness){
    this.thickness = thickness
};
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle illustrating the error?

Comment: FYI, javascript actually has booleans, you don't have to use strings !

Comment: `debugPlayer` is an object, and `processedZombiewidth` seems to be `NaN`. And `({} + NaN)` produces `"[object Object]NaN"`

Comment: As for the issue, track if back, you have `debugPlayer + processedZombiewidth`, and if you look at  `debugPlayer` it's clearly an object, and then you have `processedZombiewidth` which should have been a number, and you can't add a number and an object together and expect to get something meaningful. Then you have `parseInt(zombie1.width, 10)`, of course `zombie1` isn't defined anywhere in the code, so you get NaN

Comment: This is wrong because i am using the objects x variable which is an int and  processedzombiewidth is also an int... so i dont know why i would be getting what i am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors here:

1) `zombie1` does not have a property `width`, only `w`. Converting a non-number value using `parseInt()` will produce `NaN`.

2) You are adding the number (or rather `NaN`) to an object `debugPlayer`. This would have produced `NaN` in any case.

To fix, try adding `w` to debugPlayer's `x`:

```
//var processedZombiewidth = parseInt(zombie1.width, 10);  not needed
console.log(debugPlayer.x, zombie1.x, debugPlayer.x + zombie1.w);
```

Comment: Thank you! I hope this was a reasonable question to ask and i didnt waste you're time, but you helped me alot. thanks!